# Sum complex javascript object properties

Tags: javascript

I have a complex javascript object.

```
var obj = {foo: {bar: {baz1 : {price: 200},baz2: {price: 300}}};
```

How can I get the sum of price properties in it?
Thanks

Comment: I think recursive function is a go. Just check for property in itself, call it again for each property and so on. If not, then you have to split the layer all by yourself

Comment: Why do you think it is complex, is there any need of recursion? Normally it can be done in this way `(obj.foo.bar.baz1.price+obj.foo.bar.baz2.price)`

Comment: There is a need definitely. Because there are way a lot of baz objects.
 baz1 : {price: 200},baz2 : {price: 200}, ... , baz100 : {price: 200}

Comment: @TreeNguyen Any example? Thanks

Comment: @Artdark92 I have provide the answer. Please have a look

Comment: @TreeNguyen Works fine! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
var sum = 0;

for(var i in obj.foo.bar){

sum += obj.foo.bar[i].price;

}

console.log(sum);
```

Comment: It works. However property names of foo and bar might change and this solution will not work.
Anyway,thanks a lot for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another function with recursion to do it. For details check the code of `getPriceSum()` function - the magic is done with [**reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method and recursive calls.

```js
var obj = {
  foo: {
    bar: {
      baz1: {
        price: 200
      },
      baz2: {
        price: 300
      }
    }
  }
};

var priceSum = getPriceSum(obj);
console.log('Sum of prices is ' + priceSum);

var obj = {
  foo: {
  price: 100,
    bar: {
      baz1: {
        price: 200
      },
      baz2: {
        price: 300
      },
      baz3: {
        price: 250
      },
    }
  }
};

var priceSum = getPriceSum(obj);
console.log('Another test - prices is ' + priceSum);

function getPriceSum(obj) {
  var sum = Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(sum, prop) {
    if(typeof obj[prop] === 'object'){
      return sum + getPriceSum(obj[prop]);
    }  
    if(prop === 'price'){
      return sum + obj[prop];
    }
  }, 0);
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: Works fine! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sounds great! I'm glad that this code was helpful to you. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

jQuery

```
var sum = 0

$.each(obj.foo.bar, function(index, value) {
    sum += value.price
}); 

console.log(sum)
```

Javascript only:

```
var sum = 0

Object.keys(obj.foo.bar).map(function(objectKey, index) {
    var value = obj.foo.bar[objectKey];
    sum += value.price
});

console.log(sum)
```

Comment: It works. However property names of foo and bar might change and this solution will not work.
Anyway,thanks a lot for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can try recursive function to look into each of the property.

```
var sum = 0;
function recursive(obj) {
    $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
        if (typeof value === "object") { //is it an object?
            recursive(value);
        } else {
            sum += parseFloat(value); //if value is string, this will be 0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works fine!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a two step approach by finding all values with the given property name and then aggregate this values.

```js
function getValues(object, key) {
    return Object.keys(object).reduce(function (r, k) {
        if (object[k] && typeof object[k] === 'object') {
            return r.concat(getValues(object[k], key));
        }
        if (k === key) {
            r.push(object[k]);
        }
        return r;
    }, []);
}

var object = { foo: { bar: { baz1: { price: 200 }, baz2: { price: 300 } } } },
    result = getValues(object, 'price').reduce((a, b) => a + b);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Works fine! Thanks a lot!